# How to get value of own attribute in Observer?

Tags: event-observer, product-attribute

I create an observer to intercept when a product is added to cart. The event that i used is "salesrule_validator_process".

The problem is that i create an eav attribute, but i can't get the value of that attribute related with the observable product. Here is my code:

```
public function execute( Observer $observer ) {
  $item_attribute = $observer->getItem()->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('discount_elegible')
       ->getData();
}
```

Which retrieve something like these:

[attribute_id] => 139
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_code] => club_discount_elegible
    [attribute_model] => Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute
    [backend_model] => Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\DefaultBackend
    [backend_type] => int

And continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$item_attribute = $observer->getItem()->getProduct()->getData('discount_elegible')
```

**UPDATE:**

based on discussion with OP.

try that:

```
...
private $productRepository; 
...
public function __construct(
...
\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
...
) {
   ...
   $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
   ...
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) {
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById($observer->getItem()->getProduct()->getId());
    $attr = $product->getData('discount_elegible');
}
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin, i already tried that. But i tried it again. Now i  have a log line regardin $item_attribute in my debug.log. And it says:

[2017-03-29 19:59:49] main.DEBUG:  {"is_exception":false} []

Comment: see my updated answer.

Comment: you are very welcome sir